# angular bootstrap with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Added a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9WTNW0?p=preview

Just switch between the ng-include and the embedded div based approach in the html

HTML

```
<div id="attendee" ng-include src="'js/view/partials/attendee.html'"></div>
```

OR

```
<ng-include id="attendee" src="'js/view/partials/attendee.html'"></ng-include>
```

JavaScript

```
var self = this;
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller("AttendeeController", function($scope, $location){self.attendeesController($scope, 
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("attendee"), ['demo']);
```

it works fine but I see an error on the console for the line that triggers the bootstrap.

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

however if I've embedded html, then no error

```
<div id="attendee">
    <ul data-ng-controller="AttendeeController">
        <li data-ng-repeat="attendee in attendees">
            <a href="#/attendees/{{attendee.id}}" target="_self">{{attendee.firstName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of this stupid popup blocker in chrome and everything would work fine, weird.